# Computing the gained time

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The members of a research team frequently visit the library. Each visit takes $20$ minutes. The group decides to subscribe to a collection of research papers that they visit $90%$% of the total time spent in the library; the access time to the publications is reduced to $2$ minutes.

---

$\bullet$ What's the speed-up in the access to the publications ?

$\bullet$ How much has the average access time improved if they visit the library twice a week, $50$ weeks per year?

---

For the first question, I got : $\frac{1}{0.1 + \frac{0.9}{10}} = 5.26$ which is the correct answer as given in the textbook.

However, they get $32400 \text{ minutes} = 540 \text{ h}$ for the second question, which I don't get. How can the number of gained minutes be greater than the actual number they would spend there if there were no speed-up ?

As I see it, the total number of minutes they would normally spend on their visits is $20 \cdot 2\cdot 50 = 2000.$

What's the reasoning here?

Comment: Suppose they needed to access 2000 papers. Then before it took 40000 mins. After it took 4000 mins for 200 papers and 3600 mins for 1800 papers, total 7600 mins, a saving of 32400 mins = 540 hours.

Comment: They give the answer as 20*2*50*0.9*(20 – 2).. Can you explain ?